# Sending a mysql output using sendto function in c

Tags: mysql, c, networking

```
if(mysql_query(&mysql,msgbuf));
    else
    {
        //printf("inside else case\n");
        result=mysql_store_result(&mysql);
        //printf("\n after getting the result...\n");
        num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result); 
        //printf("\n after getting numfields...\n");
            while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
            {    
                    unsigned long *lengths; 
            //printf("\n inside while....\n");
                    lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result); 
                    for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
                    { 
                            printf("[%.*s] \t", (int) lengths[i], row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
                    }    
                    printf("\n"); 
            } 
        }
```

I am storing the result of the mysql query in result of type MSQL_RES..i would like to send this entire result to another running process using sendto(). how should i proceed??

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the Posix-[`sendto`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) function? First read the documentation.

I wouldn't do that with `sendto` because it just sends some chunk of bytes that has potentially no "meaning" at all. You don't know how `MSQL_RES` is built and used internally in the mysql-library. What if it has a bunch of pointers to dynamically allocated memory whose strcuture is only knwon inside of the mysq-library? You would have to send also these values and the receiver would have to recontruct a `MSQL_RES` object on his own. This is not going to work.

What are you trying to accomplish anyway?

Comment: I zam trying to implement a distributed database system and would like to send the queries executed at different nodes to the node which has made the request...so the result of the query needs to be sent to the callig node from all other nodes..

Comment: Well, the biggest problem is that you don't know how `MSQL_RES` works internally. That means that even by sending all bytes correctly you might not be able to reconstruct a `MSQL_RES` on your other clients. The best would be that you convert the answer into something you know (like JSON or something else) and then send it to your client. For the sending part itself I would use 0mq: http://www.zeromq.org/.